# Should I use a table or divide into 2 tables?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 4 columns:

`Count (auto increase), Sensor ID (int), Date, Value (float)`

Now, I have some rows with the "Value" field is type `Boolean`.
 Should I divide the table into 2 tables:

```
one with the "Value" is Float and other with the "Value" is Boolean (TINYINT(1)) ?
```

I know the issue with float ([Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-float.html)) and know how to solve this issue, but, I don't know without the advantage about the size of data and the accuracy, are there other advantages to split 2 tables or not ? Note that, I don't often do the "`JOIN`" Operation on my table.

Comment: Unfortunately any answer to this is going to be opinion based as this question is very broad. Generally speaking in databases, you should not be designing your tables around the language or issues, but study database normalisation to work out how your tables should be formed. And just because you don’t normally do something doesn’t mean that you should, or should not, be using it. Good luck.

Comment: you can also add a new column to table with name "is_float" and based on that you can use Value as float or store 1 / 0 and use as boolean. But it's really hard to say not knowing how will you use this table

Comment: @NoOorZ24 it is a table to store the values received from the sensor, so, with the contact sensor, it is only (on/off), but with other sensor (temperature, humidity), it is in float. I also think about set a column "is_float" in other table according to ID to know it is float or boolean, but, I don't know if I split into 2 tables, there are other advantage or not ? I will use this table to query the value of sensor, so, it doesn't often use the "JOIN"

Comment: 4 columns and 3 of them are named using SQL reserved words. Wow.

Comment: Also i'd like to know what is ID used for? Isn't that like "Name" and you can use it to determine Type of Value?

Comment: @symcbean if you use [title] it is not a problem

Comment: @symcbean, it just a way to describe the problem... not is the name I use

Comment: @NoOorZ24 the ID is the ID of sensor and I have a table to know sensor information base on the sensor ID. I can add "is_float" in this table but my question is what is better: using only one table or split into 2 tables, not how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usage and naming of columns we can discuss in comments, but about question you are really interested in:

Splitting will have an effect only if you are storing thousands of reads, not deleting them and you need something like real time searching in database. If you are not constantly reading from your DB and you don't need all results to be ASAP then there is no real need for splitting

Comment: Your column names are kinda poorly picked. I'd suggest using: id, sensor_id, date, value to make more sense. Also something like "is_float" is not needed as you can simply define in your program which sensors are float and witch bool

Comment: Thank you! An addition question, should I add a column "is_float" to identify the sensor value is in type "Float" or use a rule like if Sensor ID > 30000, it will be in type "Float"

Comment: You should use rule or predefined array because adding new column when you really don't need it is just extra complexity that will give no extra functionality